# Is there a way to upload the corrected, new question after deleting a question because I needed to correct it?

Tags: support

I deleted my question because I needed to re-write it. I tried to upload a new one, but the site tells me it's a duplicate, showing the deleted one with an undelete button for someone who wants to vote for it.

Is there a way I could send up a new question?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually posters can undelete their own "deleted" posts. Have you tried that?

Comment: Also, you can edit a "deleted" post (if you deleted it) while it remains in deleted mode, and then undelete it when you're ready to make it live again.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the deleted question only if I tried to post the new, similar query. To get it, edit it and send it up, is that the only way to get the initial post down?

Comment: Visit your profile page, click on "view all questions and answers", click on *questions*, on the bottom far left of the page there is a link: **deleted recent questions**. You should now see your "deleted" posts.

Comment: Also if you want to notify people you need to preface their username with @. As you are the owner of this post, you will always be notified when someone posts an answer or a comment. (I just happened to pass by, and saw your response).

Comment: Hmm... no reply or response. No undeleted question?